# Initializing a variable Java

Tags: java, initialization

I'm writing a simple program with a do while loop and switch, which cna accept a mathematical operation and execute it for given 2 numbers.

The problem I have is, why should I initialize the result produced by the operation to zero at the beginning.

If I don't make ans=0, it gives me errors. If the given conditions are not met, some code parts are not executed and I don't need "ans".

```
package q3;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char operator;
    float no1, no2, ans=0; // <-------------- Why should I initialize ans

    do {
        System.out.println(" Mathematical Operations to be performed :");
        System.out.println("\t * Multiplication\n\t / Division\n\t + Addition\n\t - Subtraction");
        System.out.println("Press any other character to exit");
        System.out.print("Mathematical Operator : ");
        operator = input.next().charAt(0);

        if (operator == '*' || operator == '/' || operator == '+' || operator == '-') {
            System.out.print("Number 1: ");
            no1 = input.nextFloat();
            System.out.print("Number 2: ");
            no2 = input.nextFloat();

            switch (operator) {
                case '*':
                    ans = no1 * no2;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    ans = no1 / no2;
                    break;
                case '+':
                    ans = no1 + no2;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    ans = no1 - no2;
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println("The answer of " + no1 + operator + no2 + " = " + ans);

        }
    } while (operator == '*' || operator == '/' || operator == '+' || operator == '-');

}
```

}

Comment: Why? Please rephrase your question to make more sense..

Comment: As far as Java's compiler can determine, it is possible that none of the cases in your switch statement will be matched, and `ans` will not be assigned. You may know that that is impossible, but the compiler does not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java requires that all local variables are initialised before they are used.

In your print line, you read the value of `abs`, but not all control paths set a value to it. (Even though you *think* you've covered all possibilities of your `switch` given the outer `if`, the compiler will not see things that way: some other thread could modify `operator`).

So your IDE / compiler is suggesting that you initialise it at the point of declaration.

Comment: so should I use the default case in switch here?

Comment: I would do that, and drop the `if`.

Comment: but if I drop if, the no1 and no2 values will have to be assigned and it'll be unnecessary since no operation is to be done.??!

Comment: Yup. You're stumbling upon a redesign. You should build a function that computes the *arity* of your operator. That replaces the `if`. Then you know how many arguments you need. Then you'll be able to distinguish negation from subtraction, and can handle expressions like `1 * -1'`

Comment: Nothing yet, but expression parsers tend to get more complicated. It's all about designing for future requirements.

Answer (score 3):

This is because if no case evaluates to true, the value of `ans` will not be set. So you cannot use it.

You can overcome this by adding a `default` case, and setting the value of `ans` as 0 in that.

Comment: if the given conditions haven't met this doesn't let the switch or any other code to execute, what's the point of initializing then?

Comment: @laish129 Yes, But the java compiler cannot understand all such things, because it is in `if` construct, which may, or may not evaluate !

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize `ans=0;` because you didn't have a `default` value for `ans`, for this you need to initialized it.
But if you add the defualt value you don't need to initialize it like this:

```
    ...
    case '-':
    ans = no1 - no2;
      break;
    default :
    ans = someValue; 
     break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it could be that none of the case statements apply and as a result `ans` would still be un-initialized. And since local variables have to be initialised before they are being used, you get this error.

Answer (score 2):

If you didnt initialize it, you ans will have a garbage value at first.

It is not compulsory to initialize it.

But your program will be a better program if you initialize it.

Comment: This is true for C/C++, not for Java?

Comment: In C and C++, the behaviour on reading back an uninitialised value is undefined. In Java, such a construct must fail on compilation.